# Both input and output are "Built-In Audio Analog Stereo"

Tags: sound

Just got Ubuntu for the first time.
When I go into Settings -> Sounds, I have a different input (Microphone - built-in audio) than output (Speakers - Built in audio).
However, in software/websites where there's input/output configurations (eg. Zoom, discord, google meet..), these do not appear and "Built-In Audio Analog Stereo" is the only option that appears in both input and output.
This results in the fact that everyone can hear what I hear (eg music, video), even if I'm wearing headphones, it's like my output is redirected to my input.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't select any "Monitor of ..." device for sound input in your settings? This would explain the behaviour and is made for exactly that function.

Comment: In the sound tab? I'm not seeing the word Monitor anywhere.